# SQL two "group by" in the same query

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

We have the table to track what product page a user visited.

```
product_tracking
____________________
id  user_id  product
1   1        A
2   1        B
3   2        A 
4   1        A
```

I know we can use group by user_id, and group_by product but I need both.

Expected result :

```
result_table 
____________________________
user_id      A     B    C 
  1          2     1    0
  2          1     0    0
```

any idea how to merge the 2 group by ?

Comment: Why is A counted twice for the user_id=1?

Comment: sorry my bad. I will fix it.

Comment: Maybe you should show *us* the "how" you want the data merged, so we can tell you if and how it can be done. What is the expected result set?

Comment: That is not a double group by, but something more like a pivot. Not all RDBMS support CROSSTAB selects. MySQL doesn't, AFAIK. You should look into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
SELECT
    product_tracking.user_id,
    SUM(CASE WHEN product_tracking.product='A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS A,
    SUM(CASE WHEN product_tracking.product='B' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS B,
    SUM(CASE WHEN product_tracking.product='C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS C
FROM
    product_tracking
GROUP BY
    product_tracking.user_id
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to using sum(...) is using count(...):

`SELECT
    product_tracking.user_id,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN product_tracking.product='A' THEN 1 END) AS A,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN product_tracking.product='B' THEN 1 END) AS B,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN product_tracking.product='C' THEN 1 END) AS C
FROM
    product_tracking
GROUP BY
    product_tracking.user_id`